# Test for regular files unexpectedly fails

Tags: bash

I want to write down a bash script that takes in a path name, a new directory name and some strings and copies only files in that path and its subfolders that are regular files and contain at least one of the string into a newly created directory.

In order to test my script I have created some dummy directory

```
/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:42 A
-rw-r--r-- 1 haunted85 haunted85  236 apr 13 16:42 a.out
drwxr-xr-x 2 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:43 B

/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/A:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 haunted85 haunted85   93 apr 13 16:41 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 haunted85 haunted85  101 apr 13 16:42 b.out

/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/B:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 haunted85 haunted85 4096 apr 13 16:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 haunted85 haunted85  292 apr 13 16:43 c.out
```

and here it is my script

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$#" -lt "3" ]; then
    echo "Error: cannot perform any task without enough input." 2>&1
    echo "Usage: ./creaDirectory <path_name> <dir_name> <word>[, <word2>, ..., <wordN>]"
    exit 1
else
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        # Saving pathname...
        path_name=$1
        # Moving forward
        shift

        # Saving new dir name...
        dir_name=$1
        # Moving forward
        shift

        # Creating new directory
        mkdir $dir_name

        # If correctly created...
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
            echo "$dir_name created."

            # For every file in the current directory and its subfolders...
            for file in `ls -R $path_name` 
            do
                echo "Checking $file..."
                # if the file is regular

                if [ -f $file ]; then
                    echo "$file is regular"

                     # perform other actions as well...
                else
                    echo "$file is not regular"
                fi
            done    

        else
            echo "Error: cannot create new directory." 2>&1
            exit 3
        fi 

    else

        echo "$1 does not exist or it is not a directory." 2>&1
        exit 2
    fi
fi
```

my problem is that the condition `if [ -f $file ];` doesn't seem to be working properly, as no regular file is found, but that's clearly not the case! So what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Adding the output I get. You can check yourself, these are all correct paths/filenames:

```
copia_file created.
Checking /home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/:...
/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/: is not a regular file
Checking A...
A is not a regular file
Checking a.out...
a.out is not a regular file
Checking B...
B is not a regular file
Checking /home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/A:...
/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/A: is not a regular file
Checking a.out...
a.out is not a regular file
Checking b.out...
b.out is not a regular file
Checking /home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/B:...
/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/B: is not a regular file
Checking c.out...
c.out is not a regular file
```

Comment: Got spaces in your filename/paths? Perhaps `[ -f "$file" ]` would help.

Comment: @MarcB no, there are no spaces.

Comment: If you add an extra echo to display the value of `$file` at the same time as telling you whether it is regular or not, is the value as expected? ie a correct filename?

Comment: @JoshJolly yes, they are existing correct paths/filenames.

Comment: What is your current directory when you execute the script? When you type `ls dirname` you get a list of filenames **without** the dirname. You should be using `find` not `ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `ls -R $path` is going to return filenames WITHOUT their paths, e.g. if you have

```
for file in `ls -R $path_name`
do
   echo $file
done
```

your output would be something like

```
/home/haunted85/Documenti/Sandbox/:
A
a.out
B
etc...
```

And you'll be doing

```
if [ -f A ]
```

which will fail, because `A` is not in the directory that the script is executing from.

Try

```
for file in `find $path_name -type f`
```

instead, which WILL return the full path of all matching files.

Comment: You shouldn't use either `for file in $(ls ...)` or `for file in $(find ...)` unless [you want to get errors](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)